# JSON attribute as relation type name

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
with {conatcts_count:10,account_count:20,time_stamp:'2010_12_231'} as data
merge (u:Customers1 {name:'sai',id:1})-[r:REL {conatcts_count:data.conatcts_count,account_count:data.account_count,ts:data.time_stamp}]-(s:Sale1 {name:'sales_123',id:1})
```

I have tried this... But it always creating a new nodes when I am changing the values of JSON. I am looking for something which takes the JSON timestamp and create a relation with same nodes.

[image: Data model]

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the `MERGE` command.

Usage : **MERGE** `pattern`

The merge command performs a **MATCH `pattern`** at first, and if there is no result, then it does a **CREATE `pattern`**

So if you don't have any relationship between yours `n` and `s` nodes, the MATCH returns nothing, and so ask the DB to create the pattern `(u)-[:REL]->(s)`.

What you should instead, it's this :

```
with {conatcts_count:10,account_count:20,time_stamp:'2010_12_231'} as data 
MERGE (u:Customers1 {name:'sai',id:1})
MERGE (s:Sale1 {name:'sales_123',id:1})
MERGE (u)-[:REL {conatcts_count:data.conatcts_count,account_count:data.account_count,ts:data.time_stamp}]-(s)
```